# Error when using infinity

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to generate the infinity symbol in the PDF output. But every time I type this:

```
\infty
```

I get the following message

```
    ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
    l.35 \infty
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: You need to be in math-modus, i.e. use `$\infinity$` in text or `\[\infinity\]` else.

Comment: You could create a \textinfity, just like \textbullet or \textsuperscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use this command in math mode, so simply use `$\infty$` instead.